# Tomcat handling multple domains using https

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I've got a Tomcat installation server.xml and am trying to handle multiple domains.

This is a Linux installation with Apache proxying requests to Tomcat.

```
<Connector port="8223" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="/root/keystore.jks" 
               keystorePass="xxx" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               SSLEnabled="true" proxyPort="443"/>
```

When the keystore file has an entry for a single domain - it works.

I tried to append another domain - and it does NOT work. The first one still does.

Any help?

ADDED

Right now in the Apache conf file for the domain, I've got a VirtualHost for https connection and have

```
SSLProxyEngine On

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass         /xxx  https://localhost:8227/xxx
ProxyPassReverse  /xxx  https://localhost:8227/xxx
```

I should change that to??

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass         /xxx  http://localhost:8226/xxx
ProxyPassReverse  /xxx  http://localhost:8226/xxx
```

There's an http Connector listening on 8226.

Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple certificates per connector are available beginning with Tomcat 8.5 (cf. [migration guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html#TLS_virtual_hosting_and_multiple_certificate_support_added)).

However in your case I don't see **any** security advantage in encrypting the communication between Apache Httpd and Tomcat: unless I am mistaken, they are on the same host and all communication goes through the loopback device, not a real network interface.

**Edit**: Both HTTP and HTTPS to the Apache server can be forwarded to the same plain text `<Connector>`. In order for Tomcat to distinguish the two types of requests, you need to configure Apache to send the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header:

```
RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
```

and add a `RemoteIpValve` to the `<Engine>` or `<Host>` configuration block:

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" />
```

(cf. [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html)). With the latest 7.0 servers (after version 7.0.94), you don't need to modify any of the `<Valve>`'s default parameters.

Comment: No there's no need  to - on the same backend server. but that Connector definition seems to require it. Right now on the Apache proxy_mod i've got 'SSLProxyEngine On` - should I just take that out and the whole thing works in http mode. what do i put above for proxyPort etc.?

Comment: If you want to forward HTTPS requests to a different connector you probably want to set the attributes `proxyPort="443"`, `secure="true"` and `scheme="https"` on that connector, but `RemoteIpValve` (like in the edited answer) can do this job automatically per-request.

Comment: Pls see my edit on OP. Also why does Tomcat need to distinguish between http/https? Are the RequestHeader and Valve statements just for my servlets to distinguish if need be???

Comment: Yes, if the server does not know that the original request was already sent using `HTTPS`, a `CONFIDENTIAL` constraint would cause a redirect to the same address.

Comment: Can you confirm the edit in my OP is the way to direct https requests to the http Connector.

Comment: Yes  this worked - I was able to redirect Apache https traffic to an Tomcat http Connector. The problem how is that if in one of my servlet, it detects a http url - I redirect it to https. This is causing the browser to give too many redirect error messages. Do I need to check for this X-Forwarded-Proto header in the servlet. How to avoid this continious redirects. Thanks.

Comment: The `RemoteIpValve` should take care of the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header, but before Tomcat 7.0.94 (cf. [release notes](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_7.0.94_(markt)), you need to specify `protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto"` attribute on the Valve.

Comment: Thank you - that worked and saved me a lot of manual source edits. I appreciate your help and knowledge!